# TP- Link Not working on dual boot

Tags: drivers, connection, router

Model : TL-WN725N

I have been using windows for a long time now. I haven't faces any issues with the tp-link adapter. Today i dual booted windows and ubuntu. I installed the drivers on the ubuntu and the adapter just works fine. I can connect to networks and all. But the issues came as soon as i boots between the two operating systems.

If i am on windows right now and when i reboot back to windows, the tp-link adapter can automatically detect(lights up ) and starts working, connects to netwoks, etc. But whenever i tries to reboot to ubuntu, it is not detecting or connecting to any networks. Everytime i have to manually unplug the tp-link adapter and plug it again while i am on ubuntu. Then it will work without any issues. But like i said, If i boot to windows again and boots backs to ubuntu, problem starts again.

I want the adapter to work automatically without any hassle. Can anyone help with what is going on here?

Comment: If you reboot from ubuntu back to ubuntu the adapter is working without unplugging?

Comment: @nobody yes if i reboot from ubuntu back to ubuntu adapter is working fine.  windows->windwos - OK,  ubuntu -> ubuntu - OK,  ubuntu -> windows -OK , windows -> ubuntu -NOT OK

Comment: Any thing in `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog` ?

Comment: @nobody Sorry, i am not so familiar with all the these. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: `dmesg` put the output  please, when the adapter is not accessible here https://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: @nobody I am really sorry. What output, from where?

Comment: open terminal https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal type `dmesg` in it and cp the output to the link I gave you before.

Comment: @nobody Ok i have done that.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Windows Fast Start feature. It doesn't "release' devices properly and they malfunction on other OS's.

Comment: Sorry I tried it. But the problem still exists.